# How can you import a large xlsx file front end? Out of memory issue

Tags: excel, angular, frontend, xlsx, sheetjs

Face memory out of bounds issue.
I am currently using https://github.com/SheetJS/js-xlsx library
to upload a sheet on my front end.
I keep getting an out of memory issue exceeding 36k+ rows.
"parse before potential out-of-memory crash.

Is there a different library that can handle this much data?

Comment: I am using js-xlsx on OSX Chrome and a 10kb file doesn't hang my broswer.

Answer (score 0):

> i am using PhpExcel and does not seem to have a problem importing large data. Have you tried this one, too?
>
> Also you can try `ini_set('memory_limit','16M');`